# Shell script only starting applications when used through ssh

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh

What can cause .sh scripts to work fine through an SSH shell, but not when executed through either PHP or crontab?

I have a VPS where I run game servers on, but in order to make it maintainable, I am planning on automating much of the tedious processes (like setting up or deleting the server) and making important features (like starting and stopping servers) easily acceptable for the ones who actually need it.

Now, when I made the shell scripts and tested them, they worked absolutely fine. startserver started the server, restartserver restarted it, etc. But when run from PHP, or - as I later figured out - crontab, starting servers magically does not work. Stopping them, checking if they are running, updating and all other features worked like intended, but starting a server just did not do anything. It just returned 0 while printing nothing.

For example, here is an example of a script which works in either case: (statusserver.sh)

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon -v -t --start --exec ~mta/servers/$1/files/mta-server -- -d
```

And here is one which does not work in any case: (startserver.sh)

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon -v --start --exec ~mta/servers/$1/files/mta-server -- -d
```

The only difference is that statusserver.sh has "-t", which will only tell you if doing the same command without -t will actually be successful. And executing statusserver.sh like so:

```
sudo -u mta ~mta/sh/statusserver.sh test
```

Indeed does work, printing something along the lines of "Would start ~mta/servers/test/files/mta-server -d". But doing this:

```
sudo -u mta ~mta/sh/startserver.sh $2
```

Does absolutely nothing. It does not print anything, and it actually returns 0. (which is supposed to mean the operation was successful)

Now for the fun part: When the server is already running, startserver.sh will do what it is supposed to do: Say that the server is already running, and returning an error code. (Because start-stop-daemon is kind enough to do that for me) But it flat out refuses to launch anything.

Replacing start-stop-daemon with something like:

```
sudo -u mta ~mta/servers/test/files/mta-server -d
```

Does exactly the same thing: It will just refuse to run, while still returning 0.

Oh by the way, it's not a sudo problem. Of that I am quite sure, since the following works fine too

```
sudo -u web1 sudo -u mta ~mta/scripts/startserver.sh test
```

---

So back to my question: What can cause Linux, Shell, Bash or whatever to flat out refuse to start an application when run through either PHP or crontab, while happily accepting it when launched through SSH? Is there any setting I need to switch? Any package that can be blocking up what I want to do? Any other thing I am just missing?

Comment: Did you specify the script or binary as executable file?

Comment: Yes. I am triggering shell scripts in the other users' home folder in order to accomplish the various actions, and they all function when using SSH to trigger them. However, when using PHP, the start command will not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using sudo.

Set up /etc/sudoer (using visudo) for the user that Apache runs as (usually for the 'nobody' user, or 'apache' user) as this is what Apache usually runs as. Grant sudo access to the commands you want to run, with the NOPASSWD option.

In your PHP script, use exec() to execute the commands to start/stop daemons and prefix the commands with the sudo command.

Here is an article about sudo:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/allow-a-normal-user-to-run-commands-as-root.html

Comment: I think I should have cleared this up earlier, so my apologies: The user of the PHP file (web1) already uses sudo in order to execute commands for the other user (mta). (i.e. "sudo -u mta sh /home/mta/sh/startserver.sh $1") This works fine, as all commands work. Apart from startserver.sh, which appears to be a restriction by either the webserver or something else that I can't seem to figure out. I'll edit my question in order to clear this up a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

As I think Justin was touching on, but didn't say specifically, it would seem the problem of not being able to run the script is that the apache user account (which is generally pretty limited on purpose) can't see into the user's home directory because of the permissions. Generally only the user and root can see into their own home directory. You can do a few things, sudo to run the script in the home directory, move it out of the user's home directory or possibly change permissions on the scripts/homes so they can be run in the user's home directory by apache.

Comment: This is likely not the case, as I have now tried to explain in a bit more detail in both the question itself and in response to Justin's answer. If this were the case, I wonder, wouldn't stopping servers etc also give problems? As that is currently not the case; "start-stop-daemon -v --start" just refuses to start the executable entirely, without any indication as to why, and with 0 as return code - which normally indicates success. I could just be wrong there though. Either way, I have been a bit unclear on the situation, but thanks for trying to clear that up anyway.